# The hazards in my unity game are not spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game in which you are a player cube and you have to dodge other cubes as they come through your way. The enemy cubes should spawn because of a script I have called GameController. But the cubes are not spawning. Please Help. (Also whenever my cube gets destroyed the gameover and the restart functions are not working)

I tried Recreating the prefab and the code, but nothing happened. Also, the same code is working in my other games
Here is my code:

```
void Start()
{
    gameOver = false;
    restart = false;
    restartText.text = "";
    gameOverText.text = "";
    score = 0;
    UpdateScore();
    StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves());
}

void Update()
{
    if (restart)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        }
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject hazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Length)];
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            GameObject newSpawn = Instantiate(hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);

        if (gameOver)
        {
            restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
            restart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void AddScore(int newScoreValue)
{
    score += newScoreValue;
    UpdateScore();
}

void UpdateScore()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}

public void GameOver()
{
    gameOverText.text = "Game Over!";
    gameOver = true;
}
```

}

I expect the enemies to spawn but they are not

Comment: What is the value of `hazardCount` and where do you call `GameOver` from?

Comment: And what are the value of startWait, waveWait and spawnWait?

Comment: When you add debug messages where does your code get to?

Comment: I think it should be `yield break` not `break`

Comment: @Dave, that won't make any difference. The break is for exiting the endless while loop. The coroutine will just end after the loop is exited.

Comment: @Immorality sure, it was just to point out that `yield break` should be used inside coroutines.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience guys, here is the values for startwait, wavewait etc..

Comment: `public GameObject[] hazards;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int hazardCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text restartText;
    public Text gameOverText;

    private bool gameOver;
    private bool restart;
    private int score;`

Comment: @AcidicBlaster But what values have you assigned to those fields in the Unity editor?

Comment: @AcidicBlaster You should edit your original question to include that information, rather than adding that extra info as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copy and pasted your example code into an example project. In this example your script works as expected, as you already mentioned that it works in other projects.

So in my opinion it has something to do with the inspector values. 
Check the following:
Did you checked that your hazardCount is greater than zero?
Is your hazardArray completely filled with prefabs? 
(If not that should cause the not-spawning but should also cause a null-reference-exception.)

Another option is that you make a screenshot or provide your values in the inspector somehow, so its possible to reproduce the error.

Offtopic: Your Restart after the gameOver is delayed, because the if(gameOver)-Clause comes after the WaitForSeconds(waveWait). My suggestion is to change it to the following:

```
public GameObject[] hazards;
public Vector3 spawnValues;
public int hazardCount;
public float spawnWait;
public float startWait;
public float waveWait;
public Text scoreText;
public Text restartText;
public Text gameOverText;
private bool gameOver;
private bool restart;
private int score;

private Coroutine gameRoutine;


void Start()
{
    gameOver = false;
    restart = false;
    restartText.text = "";
    gameOverText.text = "";
    score = 0;
    UpdateScore();
    gameRoutine = StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves());
}

void Update()
{
    if (restart)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        }
    }
}

IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject hazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Length)];
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            GameObject newSpawn = Instantiate(hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);    
    }
}

public void AddScore(int newScoreValue)
{
    score += newScoreValue;
    UpdateScore();
}

void UpdateScore()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}

public void GameOver()
{
    gameOverText.text = "Game Over!";
    restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
    restart = true;
    gameOver = true;
    StopCoroutine(gameRoutine);
}
```

What i have changed here is, that the if-condition is removed and the Coroutine is now stored at Start() and is directly stop as the gameOver() method gets executed. Another option instead of the StopCoroutine() would be to set the condition of your while-loop to while(!gameOver).

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, What happened is I just deleted the score text as it was not useful to me and gamecontroller started working again. Once again thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: But now my problem is that the gameover and the restart functions are not working \

Comment: Any Exception or Warning or did nothing happen?

Comment: Ok. Because of the fact, that no exception was thrown my first possible guess, that the scene is not correctly added to the build, is not possible anylonger. I would advice you to check your other scripts and add a Debug.Log() to your Gameover() method. But I think the method doesn't get executed at all because of a problem in another script. Would not be bad if you can provide more information about your other scripts or inspector values either in a new question or in the comment section here.